# Enzyme not working with karma + webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, karma-runner, enzyme

I am trying to add Enzyme to my project. When I attempt to run `karma start` I get the error `Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "airbnb" relative to directory "/Users/kieran/IdeaProjects/tahrir`. I have run `npm i --save-dev enzyme`. My `karma.conf.js` looks like

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        browsers: ['Chrome'],
        singleRun: true,
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],
        files: [
            {pattern: 'tests.webpack.js'}
        ],
        preprocessors: {
            'tests.webpack.js': ['webpack', 'sourcemap']
        },
        reporters: ['dots'],
        webpack: {
            devtool: 'inline-source-map',
            module: {
                loaders: [
                    {
                        test: /\.js$/,
                        exclude: /\/node_modules\//,
                        loader: 'babel',
                        query: {
                            presets: ['airbnb']
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            externals: {
                'cheerio': 'window',
                'react/addons': true,
                'react/lib/ExecutionEnvironment': true,
                'react/lib/ReactContext': true
            }
        },
        webpackServer: {
            noInfo: true
        }
    });
};
```

Is there something else I need to add so that webpack can access the airbnb present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error message it seems you don't have [`babel-preset-airbnb`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-airbnb) installed and you are using it in the babel loader config.

Make sure you have it installed:

`$ npm install --save-dev babel-preset-airbnb`